# GPS setting issue in android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gps

I am newbie to native android development. For understanding it, i am developing an app which will show me `gps` location of me. For this i searched on the internet and found two tutorials.

- [Link1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)
- [Link2](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/)

I am following `Link1`, and followed each step in it, Bellow is the code which I have written.

`GPSTracker.java`

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.provider.Settings;


public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 5; // 5 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 10000; // 10 seconds

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            Log.i("", "Network Value: " + isNetworkEnabled);
            Log.i("", "GPS Value: " + isGPSEnabled);
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                        this
                );
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {

                    location = locationManager

                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();

                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    }

                }

   /*                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //
    // TODO: Consider calling
   //
  // ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
 //
 // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding

 // public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
//
// int[] grantResults)
//
// to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation

// for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

                           return location;

                     }*/
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    }
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("", "Exception " + e);

    }
    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        /*if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }*/
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}}
```

Bellow is my main activity code

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btnShowLocation;
TextView textShowLocation;
// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
            // need to make canGetLocation flag true by calling below method as per your code.
            **gps.getLocation()**
            // check if GPS enabled
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                textShowLocation.append("Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude+ "\nLong: " + longitude);
            }
            else
            {
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
    });



}
```

**Update 1**

Below is my manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.accurat.tracker">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

While running the app into my device, whenever i click the `show location` button it always redirect me to the `else` part i.e. `gps.showSettingsAlert();` run. No matter if 'GPS' of my device is on it still not showing me the location. Moreover, comment or un-comment the `permission check` is not helping.

Any help would be highly appreciated:

Comment: Did you set the permissions correctly on `Manifest` ?

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge kindly see the `update 1`

Comment: Did you tried with multiple devices?

Comment: You need to call gps.getLocation() method before gps.canGetLocation()

Comment: @faisal1208 tell us the complete details which device you are testing on .. its API level and code block from which to which its going to .. debug and check the if else condition the values you are getting, then only we can help.

Comment: @Maveň I am testing it on `Samsung J7 15` and `Samsung A5`

Comment: @Maveň I have set minimum API level to `15`

Comment: as I can see the code the minimum sdk is `android:minSdkVersion="8" ` why are you lying to us?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: @Doe i had it removed from my manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `getLocation`(); method in the constructor:

```
 public GPSTracker(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    getLocation();
}
```

in your GPSTracker class add this code:

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
    getLatitude();
    getLongitude();
}
```

Also the class u are using has some problems: see this blog
http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

you can use `FusedLocationApi`

here is an example:http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html

Comment: By implementing your logic, now on `button click` my app app crashes and gives me the message `Unfortunately, Tracker has stopped`

Comment: it's giving me this error in logcat `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.accurat.tracker, PID: 10668
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: you need to instantiate `textShowLocation` first using `findviewByID` from layout

Comment: Now it's running but it's showing me lat, long `0,0` :|

Comment: try changing `MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES ` and `MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES` to `0 , 0` and check the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133946/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-rafsanahmad007).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 5.0+ version 
then add

> < uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

to your manifest.
 and if you are testing on marshmallow you have to add

```
int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION=101;
    void allowGPS() {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 {
                    Log.i("*******", "check build permission");
                    try {
                        if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                                // permission wasn't granted
                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ae) {

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ae) {
                ae.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length >= 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted
            } else {
                // permission wasn't granted
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

GPSTracker  is a service class. You have to start the service to get location. Now else condition is showing because location is not fetched yet.
You can start service by 
 `startService(new Intent(context, GPSTracker.class));`

Also change your button click code by this

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    }
```